# VBA: Create a filter that hides/shows worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I'm not that "code smart" so I'm terribly sorry for hurting your experienced eyes when gazing upon the mess below :)

The goal: create a simple filter in a master sheet that shows only the sheets that meet a specific value in a cell.

The master sheet is called "MEGAFILTER", the other sheets are called "1", "2", "3", etc. (no quotes)

How I made it work so far (again, sorry!):

```
Sub MEGAFILTER()
'
' MEGAFILTER Macro
'

'
Sheets("MEGAFILTER").Select
Range("A1").Select
Dim Filter As String
Filter = ActiveCell.Value

'This makes sure all sheets are visible (for subsequent filtering)
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next ws

'This is where the real mess kicks in
Sheets("1").Select
If [M2] = Filter Then
Sheets("1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("1").Visible = False
End If
Sheets("2").Select
If [M2] = Filter Then
Sheets("2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("2").Visible = False
End If
Sheets("MEGAFILTER").Select
Sheets("3").Select
If [M2] = Filter Then
Sheets("3").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("3").Visible = False
End If
Sheets("MEGAFILTER").Select
'ETC...
End Sub
```

100 sheets are covered like this. If there are 70 sheets present, it will of course crash when attempting to select 71. The "MEGAFILTER" select makes sure it always lands on the master sheet before it crashes. I realize this is terrible but I didn't succeed to make a proper way :(

Here's how I thought it should be:

```
Sub MEGAFILTER()
'
' MEGAFILTER Macro
'

'
Sheets("MEGAFILTER").Select
Range("A1").Select
Dim Filter As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Filter = ActiveCell.Value

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next ws

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "MEGAFILTER" Then
        If [M2] = Filter Then
        ws.Visible = True
        Else
        ws.Visible = False
        End If
        Next ws
End If

End Sub
```

But I'm getting a "Next without For" error on that. The intention is that it skips the master sheet (it shouldn't hide that one) and compares the value in cell M2 to the value in cell A1 on the master sheet. If the value is the same, it should show the sheet, if not, it should hide the sheet. Then it should move to the next sheet until all have been checked.

Believe it or not, I spent a few hours with all sorts of combinations on this before I posted this question. I feel like an idiot...

I hope someone can correct my "creativity". Thank you for reading!

Timmy

Comment: You're getting the `Next Without For` because your `For Each ws In...` loop doesn't have `Next ws` at the end of the loop (between `End If` and `End Sub`)

Comment: So cell M2 on each sheet must meet the value in `Mega Filter`!$A$1 for the sheet to be visible and multiple sheets may become visible?

Comment: is that a South Park reference :] `Next ws` should be after the last `End If` and `If [M2]` should be `If ws.[M2]`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! @Slai I made the changes you suggested and it's working perfectly now :D And yes, that is a South Park reference ^_^ How do I credit you for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Public Sub MegaFilter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Mega Filter" Then
            ws.Visible = ws.Cells(2, 13) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mega Filter").Cells(1, 1)
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

It checks if cell `M2` (`Cells(2,13)`) on each sheet equals cell A1 on `Mega Filter`.

In Excel VBA `TRUE = -1` and `FALSE = 0`.  The numerical value for `xlSheetHidden` is `0`, `xlSheetVisible` is `-1`.

So, if M2=A1 TRUE is returned (-1) and the sheet is made visible, otherwise FALSE is returned (0) and the sheet is hidden.

Comment: Cool, that works too! VBA is awesome, shame my mind has trouble getting it right =)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub HideSheet()

Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set sheet = ActiveSheet

    ' this hides the sheet but users will be able 
    ' to unhide it using the Excel UI
      sheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden

    ' this hides the sheet so that it can only be made visible using VBA
   sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

 End Sub
```